# Добавление анимации на префаб из другого скрипта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

всем привет, имеется такой скрипт:

```
public class Hero : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController hero;
    public float speed = 10;
    public float gravity = 5F;
    private Vector3 moveDirection;

    GameObject[] tree =  GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tree");
    private AnimationClip NewAnimationn;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {                
        hero = gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();             
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

        if (hero.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= speed;

            // раскоментировать для прыжка
            // if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            //     moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

        }
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        hero.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            for (int i=0;i<tree.Length;i++)
            {
               var p= tree[i].GetComponent<Animation>();
                p.AddClip( NewAnimationn,"TimeLapse");
                p.Play();                                       
            }
        }
}
```

На сцене имеется префаб- дерево, и не одно, на все префабы я добавил тег "tree" - и на строке

```
GameObject[] tree =  GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tree");
```

- ищу объекты по тегу и запихиваю их в массив, затем при нажатии кнопки D(У меня и персонаж в сторону двигается) и я перебера этот массив - т.е обращаюсь к каждоиу объекту с таким тегом и его компоненте анимация и все это присваиваю в поле с именем p , что бы потом на нем вызвать метод AddClipp() - с помощью которого добовить к каждому префабу дерева нужную мне анимацию, которую я по идее должен передать в качестве аргумента AddClipp()
Как мне в поле NewAnimationn - передать ссылку на 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
то вообще анимация? почему спрашиваю? Потому что не знаю! Ведь в проекте также создался файл 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И как я понимаю это сам файл анимации, а первый - это так называемый аниматор. Разъясните что к чему.
И последнее - Unity исключение 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- при нажатии на клавишу A . В студии же это строка 
`for (int i=0;i<tree.Length;i++)` - т.е начало цикла

Comment: Есть в юнити `Animation` а есть `Animator` - это немного разные вещи. Поэтому нужно как минимум разобраться что за компонент там на дереве у вас всё таки висит и какой метод, в зависимости от этого уж вызывать........так что же у вас на самом деле там имеется?

Comment: Кстати `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tree");` нужно делать в методе `Start` или `Awake`, т.к. в режиме редактора он ничего не знает об объектах сцены....поэтому на момент старта там ничего будет

Comment: "Кстати GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tree"); нужно делать в методе Start или Awake" -Спасибо. Исправил. Только один вопрос - когда я переношу GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tree"); в  Start - поле воспринимается как локальное, сделать static оно его не позволяет. Как быть?

Comment: И да, спасибо, что отвечаете.

Comment: Саму переменную вы объявляете у класса `public GameObject[] tree;`......а уже в методе инициализируете `void Start() { tree = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tree"); }`